# How does Ruby Implement General Delimited Inputs?

Tags: ruby

After much searching, I can't figure how Ruby implements [General Delimited Inputs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UB).

All I can find is [Kernel#`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60), which is used by `%x{...}`.

Any help would greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to find where in the ruby source these are implemented?

Comment: This is a part of the syntax. I doubt you can find it through the docs

Comment: @DaveS. Yes, I'd like to find the source code.

Comment: Might be best to start in [`parse.y`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/parse.y#L7738). These forms of quoting are language features, they're not Ruby methods.

Comment: I don't why this is being downvoted.  It's a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled in the parsing code, which is written in [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) and C.  Check out [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_195/parse.y#L7738).  Specifically, the token that handles this type of quoting begins with `tQWORDS_BEG` (search within `parse.y`).

A detailed discussion of the YACC implementation would be long, but if you want to get started, that's where it lives in the code.

Note that the above link is for MRI Ruby.  I don't know how other Ruby interpreters handle it, but they all do it in a parser somewhere, and most of those are written in C and likely use YACC to parse.  Notable exceptions are JRuby, written in Java, and druby, in OCaml.

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L7758 - This is where it is in the source.